# Parsing HTML with <DIV> class to variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to parse a server monitoring page which doesnt have any  class name . The HTML file looks like this

```
<div style="float:left;margin-right:50px"><div>Server:VIP Owner</div><div>Server Role:ACTIVE</div><div>Server State:AVAILABLE</div><div>Network State:GY</div>
```

how do i parse this html content to a variable like

```
$Server VIP Owner
$Server_Role Active
$Server_State Available
```

Since there is no class name.. i am struggling to get this extracted.

```
 $htmlcontent.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('div') | ForEach-Object {
>>     New-Variable -Name $_.className -Value $_.textContent
```

Comment: Its just a string. So capture the string and parse it as a string. Then pick the major "Div"

Comment: `$htmlcontent.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerText |ConvertFrom-StringData -Delimiter ':'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are only showing us a very small part of the HTML, it is very likely there are more `<div>` tags in there.

Without an `id` property or anything else that uniquely identifies the div you are after, you can use a `Where-Object` clause to find the part you are looking for.

Try

```
$div = ($htmlcontent.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('div') | Where-Object { $_.InnerHTML -like '<div>Server Name:*' }).outerText

# if you're on PowerShell version < 7.1, you need to replace the (first) colons into equal signs
$result = $div -replace '(?<!:.*):', '=' | ConvertFrom-StringData

# for PowerShell 7.1, you can use the `-Delimiter` parameter
#$result = $div | ConvertFrom-StringData -Delimiter ':'
```

The result is a Hashtable like this:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Server Name                    VIP Owner
Server State                   AVAILABLE
Server Role                    ACTIVE
Network State                  GY
```

Of course, if there are more of these in the report, you'll have to loop over divs with something like this:

```
$result = ($htmlcontent.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('div') | Where-Object { $_.InnerHTML -like '<div>Server Name:*' }) | Foreach-Object {
    $_.outerText -replace '(?<!:.*):', '=' | ConvertFrom-StringData
}
```

---

Ok, so the original question did not show what we are dealing with..
Apparently, your HTML contains divs like this:

```
  <div>=======================================</div>
  <div>Service Name:MysqlReplica</div>
  <div>Service Status:RUNNING</div>
  <div>Remarks:Change role completed in 1 ms</div>
  <div>=======================================</div>
  <div>Service Name:OCCAS</div>
  <div>Service Status:RUNNING</div>
  <div>Remarks:Change role completed in 30280 ms</div>
```

To deal with blocks like that, you need a whole different approach:

```
# create a List object to store the results
$result  = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
# create a temporary ordered dictionary to build the resulting items
$svcHash = [ordered]@{}

foreach ($div in $htmlcontent.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('div')) {
    switch -Regex ($div.InnerText) {
        '^=+' { 
            if ($svcHash.Count) {
                # add the completed object to the list
                $result.Add([PsCustomObject]$svcHash)
                $svcHash = [ordered]@{}
            }
        }
        '^(Service .+|Remarks):' { 
            # split into the property Name and its value
            $name, $value = ($_ -split ':',2).Trim() 
            $svcHash[$name] = $value 
        }
    }
}
if ($svcHash.Count) {
    # if we have a final service block filled. This happens when no closing
    #   <div>=======================================</div>
    # was found in the HTML, we need to add that to our final array of PSObjects
    $result.Add([PsCustomObject]$svcHash)
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\services.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output on screen using the above example:

```
Service Name Service Status Remarks                          
------------ -------------- -------                          
MysqlReplica RUNNING        Change role completed in 1 ms    
OCCAS        RUNNING        Change role completed in 30280 ms
```

Comment: Thanks Leo. Much appreciate your help with this. Apologies for not showing the full html code. I am getting error like ```ConvertFrom-StringData : Data item 'Service Status' in line 'Service Status=RUNNING' is already defined.``` Below is snapshot of the html code

Comment: ```<div>=======================================</div><div  >Service Name:MysqlReplica</div><div  >Service Status:RUNNING</div><div  >Remarks:Change role completed in 1 ms</div><div>=======================================</div><div  >Service Name:OCCAS</div><div  >Service Status:RUNNING</div><div  >Remarks:Change role completed in 30280 ms</div>``` this keeps repeating for a total of 43 services. Also there are two different server with one Active and another as stand-by. What i was looking is to get this converted to a variable and then i can put it in a table with name and service status.

Comment: Thanks Theo. Apologies for the typo

Comment: @Enigma Using your completely new HTML setup, I have added new code

Comment: Thanks Theo for being such a star.  I couldn't have done it without you and i am still trying to understand the code you have written which works like a charm.. Much appreciated.